# How to send mail in table format with data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table, html-email

I have table in my PHP file which is looks like this.

```
<div class="table-main" style="width:600px;" id="data-table-grid">
<table class="font order">
<tr>
<td>Item</td>
<td>Price</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <span class="tdlist head">Party packs</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="tdlist">Tango Pack</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        $<span class="price">60</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='text' class="item_input text-box" maxlength=9 name='item1' value='0' id='item2' style="width:60px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <span></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="tdlist">Gala Pack </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        $<span class="price">100</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='text' class="item_input text-box" maxlength=9 name='item2' value='0' id='item2' style="width:60px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <span></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to send this table output same as in mail with the filled data. I tried with this:

```
  var msg = $("#data-table-grid").prop('outerHTML');
```

and I send mail and I got table format but I got an empty table. I want to get mail with the filled values.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you only want to send html data than use var msg = $(".table-main").html();

Comment: @ManojGarwa will it send table with its value?

Comment: @ManojGarwa i have tried with this way but i am not getting text-box value

Comment: Off cource you dont want to send tags with <input type ....> right?
In that case you can tweak with some jquery stuff. on click of button (when you click to submit mail) get value of each input type and set that value to its parent TD's text. after that get value of particular DIV as i written above in my first comment but with some setTimeout. try this, might it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Turn the whole thing into a string and add it to the body of your mail. Change the "double quotes" too 'single quotes' and will work, just a little time consuming.

```
$mystring = "<Everything in here>";
```

Comment: I think you will have better success with Manoj Garwa Answer. But I am unable to bump it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this php file seperate in directory than use

$str=file_get_contents(file path);

Now if you want to change some variable n this string tjan you can replace that too.

For examplr at first we define some special syntax in data file to be included such as ~~full_name~~.

Than now you can replace it dynamically here in mail sending page such as

$str = Str_replace("~~full_name~~", $fullName, $str);

And now you can use this above variable $str as body part of your email.

And one more important thing to keep in mind that in headera of your mail set content-type="text/html"

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your table and div closing tags are missing. i hope in your original code you have them

also, `#data-table-grid` is your div not your table, so getting outer html will get the div as well, which you dont need.

you can do

```
 var msg = $("#data-table-grid").html():
```

which will take the div's innerHTML which includes the table with values.
if you still need the div too however, refer to its parent's inner html as follows:

```
 var msg = $("#data-table-grid").parent().html():
```